# Unable to fetch exact number of elements in php array from sql database

Tags: php

I have a database table called user which only have one entry in it. After making connection I do this

```
function dbQuery($sql)
    {
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    return $result;
    }
```

this runs the query received. Then

```
function getUser(){
    $sql = "select username from user";
    return dbQuery($sql);
}
```

Now I call this `getUser()` function to fetch the username

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array(getUser())){
    echo($row['username']);
  }
```

**the problem is that it prints the username infinitely. Please Help**

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated! try to use mysqli_query(). http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array(getUser())){
```

The execution of this is:

1. call `getUser`
2. call `mysql_fetch_array` on the result
3. assign result to `$row`
4. **repeat from 1.**

You are calling `getUser()` over and over, getting a new result set every time. Call it once and save the result to a variable.

Comment: `$row=mysql_fetch_array(getUser());
  while($row){
   echo($row['username']);
  }`
I tried this but no effects

Comment: Please look at a real example of how to use those functions: http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array. Please also notice the big read box on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `getUser()` which regenerates the result in loop.

This code will do the the thing:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array(getUser());
echo $row['username'];
```

MySQL extension is deprecated so consider moving to different one as per derWilly's comment

Answer (score -1):

since you want only one row as result, consider to use
mysql_fetch_row();

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row(getUser());
```

that will return an array in $row with the fields of that row.

anyway, if you still want to use mysql_fetch_array() dont forget to pass a second argument for the type of the result array (MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, or MYSQL_BOTH)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(getUser(), MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo($row[0]); 
}
```